# What's the name of this Space Marine Commander?

Tags: warhammer-40k

I've got him as a gift and don't know where it was bought. Material is metal, hand-painted by gifter (by the original scheme I believe).

Any suggestions on his id?

[image: Picture 1]
[image: Picture 2]
[image: Picture 3]

Comment: This question imay, or may not, also be on-topic at the [stack RPG site](http://rpg.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**The figure is Brother Captain Avann Stern of the [Grey Knights](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Grey_Knights#.UPmXxid9JLc). The Grey Knights are a Space Marines Chapter and the Chamber Militant for the [Ordo Malleus](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Ordo_Malleus). The Chapter specialises in the hunting and extermination of Chaos daemons.**

[image: Brother-Captain Stern Painted with the colors of the Grey Knights Order]

*Brother-Captain Stern Painted with the colors of the Grey Knights Order wielding a Nemesis Force Weapon and Storm-bolter*

**We have [james](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/12020/james) to thank for the figure identification. Most of what I determined is still true.**

- Captain Avann Stern is a decorated Terminator Captain and Psyker. This can be determined by the book on his left hip, the swash on his right shoulder pad and the open tome on his left shoulder pad. His forehead has two, maybe three service studs indicating at least 50 years, maybe more of active service in the name of the God-Emperor. What is obscured on your figure is the Imperial Eagle on his forehead.
- Captain Stern is wearing Terminator Armor, wielding a [Storm Bolter](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Storm_Bolter) and a [Nemesis Force Weapon](http://wh40k.lexicanum.com/wiki/Nemesis_Force_Weapon). The armor design is rather archaic in appearance, making me believe he is either a highly converted or customized figure. His appearance reminds me of early figure designs before more standardized designs were created. His armor is an ancient relic he has worn for over four centuries of service.
- It is also uncommon for modern figures to wear a libram (book) at their hip. Many modern figures show the libram open over the head of the Librarian.
- Captain Stern is a highly decorated soldier, with at least three phylacteries visible, one on a belt, one on his chest plate (called the Crux Terminatus) and one on the upper left breastplate. Two are contained and one is an open version called a Purity Seal on the armor proper. In the lore of the Space Marines, he would have been a soldier of some renown.

> - A Grey Knights Brother-Captain ranks below a Grand Master and is in command of one hundred of the galaxy's finest warriors - a heavy responsibility, but one undertaken with sombre dignity. Upon the battlefield, a Brother-Captain will be found at the forefront of the fighting, grinding his foes beneath his feet, setting an example for his Battle-Brother to live up to and commanding his troops through psychic communication.

**[Brother Captain Avann Stern](http://warhammer40k.wikia.com/wiki/Arvann_Stern)**

> - Stern's fate is inextricably linked with that of the Lord of Change named M'Kachen, the instigator of the Cult of the Red Talon. During the Ordo Malleus's destruction of the cult, Stern faced and banished the daemon back into the warp for one hundred years and a day.
> - When the daemon was able to return to the mortal realm he was determined to find Stern and devour his soul. The two have faced each other in battle several times. If unable to personally face Stern, M'kachen sends one of his most powerful servants to attempt the deed for him. Stern has battled M'kachen three times so far. Each time, the Brother-Captain has proven his ability to withstand the power of the daemon and defeat the creature.
> - Stern also took part in the final stages of the Siege of Vraks in late M41, helping defeat the Daemon Prince Uraka Az'baramael.

Comment: [james' answer is correct](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/30688/770). The model is Brother Captain Stern of the Grey Knights. I've added the reference to GW's website.

Comment: I left the question open for days while I researched. I could not find him because of the modifications/conversions made to the figure. I still think this particular figure is an older model. I will make the appropriate edits. The model is indeed Brother Captain Stern of the Grey Knights.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't implying the info you posted wasn't interesting :) Just that the particular model had been identified.

Comment: No. I appreciate his efforts in finding the name. The paint job made it challenging for me. I am happy the answer has been resolved. I tried to reverse engineer it from the figure. I hoped it might help someone else get closer than I did. I just made an update to the information so a person could get a bit of an overview on the character.

Answer (score 10):

That model is brother captain stern of the grey knights.

[Here is the reference from Games Workshop](http://www.games-workshop.com/gws/catalog/productDetail.jsp?prodId=prod1190019a&_requestid=1666055).

Comment: A guess, or can you source that?

Comment: @Xantec James is right. I just found it on GW's website, and added the link.

Comment: @AndresF. Thanks.